# How To Fix My BackStack Issue In Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack

I have an Activity A that loads Fragment F 10 times; once for each question in an array list. The problem is that if I am viewing question No. 4 and I decide to go back ( I have a button to navigate back and another one to go forward), it seems to never forget that particular position ( No. 4) because after reaching question No. 1, if I click the NEXT (or forward button), it jumps back to question No. 4 instead of question No. 2.

Here is the code that loads a new fragment with the new question:

```
@Override
public void onNextQuestion(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Log.d("ANSWERS", " " + finalAnswers.size());
    if(new_position == questions.size()-1){
        setFragment(new SurveyEmailFrag(), "emailFrag");
    }else{
        bundle.putString("question", questions.get(new_position+1));
        SurveyQuestionFrag newSurveyFrag = new SurveyQuestionFrag();
        newSurveyFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        Log.d("NEWFRAG", " " + newSurveyFrag.answer);
        if(new_position < questions.size()){
            setFragment(newSurveyFrag, "frag_" + new_position);
            new_position++;
            Log.d("POS", ""+new_position);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the utility method to set fragments:

```
public void setFragment(Fragment frag, String tag)
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.surveyContainer);
    if(fragment == null)
    {
        ft.add(R.id.surveyContainer, frag, tag);
    } else {
        ft.replace(R.id.surveyContainer, frag, tag);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

When I click the PREV button, I do this:

```
@Override
public void onPreviousMove(){
    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Every time I set a new Fragment, I add it to the **back stack** and every time someone clicks the PREV button, I pop the back stack. So I am confused (Still new to Android) and don't know how to solve this issue:

All I would like to see is that when I click the NEXT button, it should go to the next question (which mathematically would be currentQuestion+1, and when I click the previous button, it should go to currentQuestion-1, and that should be true no matter where I stop and change direction.

Thanks in advance. Every help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest using a viewpager

Comment: Some example code would be helpful.

Comment: A down vote? I would like to at least know what I did wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it guys! I might consider using a better solution in the future but for now, all I had to do was reverse the course in the PREV button and check the array index to avoid the exception.

Here is the PREV button code functionality that I needed for it to work:

First, do not add the fragments to the back stack when you set them. Then do this:

```
@Override
public void onPrevQuestion(){
    //TODO : do some magic here to reverse course
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Log.d("ANSWERS", " " + finalAnswers.size());


    if(new_position > 0){
        bundle.putString("question", questions.get(new_position-1));
        SurveyQuestionFrag newSurveyFrag = new SurveyQuestionFrag();
        newSurveyFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        setFragment(newSurveyFrag, "frag_" + new_position);
        new_position--;
        Log.d("POS", ""+new_position);
    }else{
        setFragment(new RateExperienceFrag(), "rateEx");
    }


}
```

Thanks to those who suggested ideas.